# Create an empty ABAddressBook in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook, abaddressbook

Can I create an ABAddressBook which does not read data from my address book. i.e. it's empty to start with so that I can put in my own contacts fetched from the internet.

As you may know the function

```
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
```

gives me data from the built in addressbook. This is not what I want but if you know a solution to my problem please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to have an empty instance of ABAddressBook. The documentation is only about getting an ABAddressBook filled with the address book of the iPhone.

Comment: No, it's probably not possible. Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making an array (or mutablearray) that you fill with the contacts and put the array inside a `UITableView`.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do now. Making my own peoplepicker :P
I had hoped for a easier soulution but there probably is none.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a "private contacts" app which stores contacts off of the normal address book and I can confirm that this is indeed possible, if only through a little manipulation. Using the ABAddressBookRef variable, however, won't help you at all. What you need is a NSMutableArray of ABRecordRef's, which is how iOS stores its contacts.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to zero out ABAddressBookRef with a memset/calloc and see if that gives you the desired result.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these functions so I don't know how you mean I should use them.